# How to avoid null implementation of interface methods

Tags: java, design-patterns

There may be some problem in my design too. Here is my problem:

I have AbstractCustomAuthHandler which first;

- gets IUser (gets users with implementing logic)
- than calls IUser's IRole object's function (gets roles with the implementing logic)

So in the beginnig of the design;

- every IUser implementation has some IRole logic
- those are seperated because they are separate rest calls in seperate microservices
- but I related them with IUser has a IRole relation

But now there is some implementations that some IUser's implementation should not have IRole object. So for now I'm returning null for this implementations and I didn't like it. I thought about splitting the intefaces but couldn't find the solution which satisfies by AbstractCustomAuthHandler too. Here is a diagram and the code:

[image: Here is the design for the auth]

Here is the some part of AbstractCustomAuthHandler

```java
IUser userAuth= this.getUserAuth();
final Response userResponse= userAuth.findUser();
// ...
Map<String, Object> attributes= userAuth.getMappedAttributes();
// ...
IRole roleAuth= userAuth.getRoleAuth();
if (roleAuth!= null)
{
    final Response rolesResponse = roleAuth.findRolesBy();
}
// ....
```

Here is AuthMethodWithoutRole that I have problem about returning null

```java
public class AuthMethodWithoutRole implements IUser
{
    @Override public Response findUserBy( )
    {
        // some logic
    }

    @Override public IRole getRoleAuth( )
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Here is IUser interface

```java
public interface IUser extends IAuth
{
    Response findUserBy();

    IRole getRoleAuth();
}
```

Here is IRole interface

```java
public interface IRole
{
    Response findRolesBy( );
}
```

Comment: You neither like hrowing a `RuntimeException`, do you? You can use a `default` implementation in the interface, but that would just put the `return null;` or an `Exception` in a different place.

Comment: Which Java version are you using? If it's >=8 you can use Optional (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html). Have you already considered it?

Comment: I'm using 8. Yes but either making Optional.empty or default implementation makes it still consider the callers if it has the check role auth.

Comment: Your design requires a check. If you split the users into two or more different ones, then you will have to check of which type the current user is, if you don't you will either have to check for `null` or `catch` an `Exception`. Google for suitable design patterns.

Comment: Actually I can split users into 2 interfaces and those interfaces can extend one at the top, lets call it IAuth. Also I can say that in the IAuth -> hasRoleAuth.  So AbstractHandler checks if hasRoleAuth, than it can cast IAuth to -> IUser if hasRoleAuth. Than available to use getRoleAuth after casting. This may be a solution but want to think if a cleaner way exist

Comment: The patter decorator is a good idea?

Comment: As a separate issue, it is not Java practice to use `I` for interfaces.

Comment: I know, my newly joined team's decision it is which can't be changed in this legacy code

Answer (score 1):

Why you not just create a class NullRole implements IRole?
So you do not need the AuthMethodWithoutRole. You can just use your default AuthMethod dealing with a "NullRole".

Comment: But implementing interface with null implementation doesn't make sense since interface is a contract. I want to avoid this while keep handler useful

Comment: @cmlonder You may be misunderstanding the suggestion, which is to apply the Null Object pattern. Another name might be `NoRole` or `AnonymousRole`.

Comment: Note that we could also just use java Optional that serves this purpose and that is standard now. Besides, the actual problem is how to avoid the conditional statement about the role value. Optional or Null Object pattern will not spare that. In fact, the current design prevents that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want really remove the role check from `AbstractCustomAuthHandler`, you should  rethink your design. You could move the logic that uses the role in the IUser class/subclasses.
In this way each IUser implementation will use it if required.
This approach sounds a DDD approach.  Making objects collaborate according to their nature/definition and don't let an artificial object to perform the whole logic (`AbstractCustomAuthHandler`).

This logic  :

```
IUser userAuth= this.getUserAuth();
final Response userResponse= userAuth.findUser();
// ...
Map<String, Object> attributes= userAuth.getMappedAttributes();
// ...
IRole roleAuth= userAuth.getRoleAuth();
if (roleAuth!= null)
{
    final Response rolesResponse = roleAuth.findRolesBy();
}
```

would be done in `IUser` :

```
IUser userAuth= this.getUserAuth();
Response response = userAuth.computeResponse(...);
```

Or maybe :

```
ResponsePart responsePart = userAuth.computeSomePartOfTheResponse(...);
// and use responsePart  to complete the logic.
```

Of course `IUser` subclass could rely on some base method defined in a super class or in the interface to perform the common logic.

---

If you don't want to change your approach, that is you want to go on retrieving roles information for the IUser object in order to let another class (`AbstractCustomAuthHandler`) to use it, you need to manipulate uniformally IUser for the class that manipulates them.
So providing implementation with empty or null roles is required even for subclasses that don't have these.
I don't think that it is a design issue if you follow this approach.    As improvement you could consider :

- Define a default implementation in the interface that returns null.
- Or change the return type to `Optional<Role>` and define a default implementation in the interface that returns an `empty` Optional.

This would give :

```
public interface IUser extends IAuth
{
    Response findUserBy();

    default Optional<IRole> getRoleAuth(){return Optional.empty()}
}
```

Now override the method only when it is required.